# Jquery - if .find returns nothing

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <extraslist>
        <extra 
            id="0"
            enabled="1"
            quantityavailable="2"
            displayindex="1">
            <extraname>Example 1</extraname>
            <extradesc>Example 1 Description</extradesc>
        </extra>
        <extra 
            id="1"
            enabled="1"
            displayindex="2">
            <extraname>Example 2</extraname>
            <extradesc>Description 2</extradesc>
        </extra>
    </extraslist>
```

And a .find function that finds each extra and displays the result on a web page.

```
$(xmlExtras).find('extra').each(function(){

});
```

How would I go about writing a function so that if all 'extras' = enabled="0" to do something...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update after reading question properly**

You can check the length of the `find` result using an extra selector:

```
var $enabledExtras = $(xmlExtras).find('extra[enabled="1"]');

if ($enabledExtras.length == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/mM42a/)

Comment: I just changed extra[enabled="1"] and that works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @nsilva no problem, I've updated the example to include quotes as well

Answer (score 0):

You should try..

```
$(xmlExtras).find('extra').each(function(i){
    if($(this).find('enabled) == 0)
    {
       do something...
    }
    else
    {

    }

});
```

Additional information: such situation you should try on JSON.

Answer (score 0):

heh, I was pulled out to a phone call, but I got this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/H3eFM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code should help you

```
var xmlText='<?xml version="1.0"?><extraslist><extra id="0" enabled="1" quantityavailable="2" displayindex="1"><extraname>Example 1</extraname></extra></extraslist>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlText);

$(xmlDoc).find('extra').each(function(){
//All your code goes here
});
```